# Is this prime number hypothesis correct ? And if it isn't what would it contribute to math if it was?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

I have an hypothesis and I tried a lot of prime numbers on it and it worked , so if this hypothesis is correct ; How can it contribute to math ?

1. Let $y$ be a non-zero natural number;
2. Let $p_y$  be the $y$th prime number, indexing from 1. E.g. $p_1 = 2$.
3. Let $\sigma_1(y)$ be the divisor sum of $y$.

The hypothesis is

$$\frac{(p_y+y)p_y}{2 \ln\left(\frac{(p_y+y)p_y}2\right) \ln( k p_y^n )} \approx 1$$

where $k = 7.63575844860837$ and
$$n=\frac{(\sigma_1(y)+y)\sigma_1(y)+(p_y+y)p_y}{2\ln\left(\frac{(\sigma_1(y)+y)\sigma_1(y)+(p_y+y)p_y}2\right) \ln(kp_y)}$$

Comment: You define $p_y(X)$ as "the $y$th natural number". There's two issues with that line - first, $X$ doesn't seem to be used; second, isn't "the $y$th natural number" just $y$? I'm guessing perhaps you mean "$p_y$ is the the $y$th *prime* number", is that right?

Comment: With some rearrangement, your hypothesis could also be expressed as
$$ \frac{\alpha_y}{\ln \alpha_y} \approx \ln k + \frac{\alpha_y + \beta_y}{\ln (\alpha_y + \beta_y)} \frac{\ln p_y}{\ln(kp_y)}, \quad \alpha_y \equiv \frac{(p_y+y)p_y}{2}, \; \beta_y \equiv \frac{(\sigma_1(y)+y)\sigma_1(y)}{2}$$
in case it's useful. Also, maybe it will help to explain how you came to this particular hypothesis. I doubt you constructed the structure simply by looking at the numerical values.

Comment: Also, when you say you tried a lot of prime numbers? It would help to know (roughly) how many. $10^{10}?$ or $10^{20}?$ or...

Comment: Also, what has this to do with the Riemann hypothesis ?

Comment: $k$ is quite close to $e^2$, and using this value seems to improve the result (taking $y$ up to $10^4$ and looking at the root mean square of the difference of the formula from $1$). Although, checking on that range again, the optimal $k$ value is around $1.6314$, so now I'm wondering where the original $k$ value came from. @Peter I wonder if it's related to the reformulation of RH using the divisor function? (See the end of this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function )

Comment: I've used @TonyMathew 's reformulation to get a partial answer using the prime number theorem. Any thoughts on how to finish the answer off?

Comment: @TonyMathew Thank you very much for your work .

Comment: @ChrisLewis Thank you very much .

Comment: @ChrisLewis is it possible for me to add another hypothesis that can complete the response ?

Comment: Sure, although if it's very different it might be worth asking as a separate question

Answer (score 4):

Per @Tony Mathew's comment, the hypothesis is equivalent to

$$\frac{\alpha_y}{\log{\alpha_y}} \approx \log{k} + \frac{\alpha_y+\beta_y}{\log{\left(\alpha_y+\beta_y\right)}} \frac{\log{p_y}}{\log{k p_y}}$$

where
$$\alpha_y=\frac{\left(p_y+y\right)p_y}{2},\quad \beta_y=\frac{\left(\sigma_1(y)+y\right)\sigma_1(y)}{2}$$

Define $f(x)=\frac{x}{\log{x}}$. By the prime number theorem, $f(x)\approx \pi(x)$, where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

Now, the hypothesis is
$$f\left(\alpha_y\right)\approx \log{k} + f\left(\alpha_y+\beta_y\right)\frac{\log{p_y}}{\log{kp_y}}$$

If we let $K=\log{k}$, this becomes
$$f\left(\alpha_y\right)- f\left(\alpha_y+\beta_y\right)\frac{1}{1+\frac{K}{\log{p_y}}} \approx K$$

but for large enough $y$, $\frac{K}{p_y}$ will be negligible, leading to
$$f\left(\alpha_y\right)- f\left(\alpha_y+\beta_y\right)\approx K$$

Now note that $f$ is increasing; so we would expect $K=\log{k}$ to be negative. The hypothesis now becomes a question about the number of primes between $\alpha_y$ and $\alpha_y+\beta_y$, but I don't know how to go any further with the particular forms these numbers take.